# recover lost vim session after exiting

Tags: vim

I went to the first version(by mistake) while recovering from a crashed session, saved it and exited. And I realized what a big mistake I made. Is there anyway I can recover all the changes I had made. The .swp file got lost when I exited.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is why source control systems are important.

Comment: Very unfortunate. Thanks